# PHP: Search a folder of images using meta data?

Tags: php, image, metadata, meta-tags

I'm starting a project that involves upwards of 500 images that need will need to be searchable.

Is it possible to add keywords to an images meta data and then use PHP to retrieve an image with that searched keyword?

Comment: If you choose to store your metadata in a table in a database, you can easily attach multiple keywords and search in that (and achieving what you want a hellofalot easier)

Answer (score 1):

PHP lets you read EXIF data:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Alternatively you could use a database to index the EXIF data. Reading the image data for every search query is a lot of work, so you should consider updating the database table when an image is uploaded.

Comment: That is a good idea. But the client is handing me over 500+ images I hope to place in a folder and make them searchable. I'm able to request that the client provides the images in which ever format I wish, and require them to insert any meta data. This is what will help keep my cost of doing to project lower.

Comment: 500 images should be pretty easy to index and store in a database (only the metadata, not the actual images). Even if you keep the metadata stored in the files instead of the database PHP should be able to crawl through 500 files in only a tenth of a second. (Don't use it for large websites, but it's okay to use it for stuff like admin backends)